# Up Navigation for a fragment build on top of another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigationbar

I have a `FragmentX` which I have to provide navigation up, so I am using the code below. But the problem is that this fragment is not on top of an Activity directly, but of another fragment(which then is on top of an Activity)
If I apply the code below is indeed furnished up navigation to the fragmentX, but also to the fragment below( and other tab fragment below)
I want to provide the up navigation only to FragmentX.

I know that is not a nice architecture but I cannot change

```
       val view = container?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entries_list)
       val actionBar = activity.supportActionBar

       actionBar?.apply {
           elevation = .0f
           setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
       }
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't exactly visualize your requirement. If you just want the setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) on FragmentX, weird way would be setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) on onStop() method of fragment. There should be a more cleaner way but.

Comment: it works but only onDestroy! thank you very much

Comment: you can use setUserVisibleHint() method too.  Adding my comment as answer replacing onStop to onDestroy so if someone else wants to refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want have setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) only on FragmentX not on other fragments of activity, one way would be *setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)* on onDestroy() method of FragmentX or userVisibleHint method.

```
public class FragmentX extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if ( !isVisibleToUser ) {
              //setting it as false
              setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}
```